# Is a comma used for introducing subclause?

Tags: comma, subordinate-clause

> (a) Thema des Schaubilds ist wie viele Stunden die Studenten an unserer Uni pro Woche arbeiten.
>
> (b) Thema des Schaubilds ist, wie viele Stunden die Studenten an unserer Uni pro Woche arbeiten.

Which one is correct? Do we need a comma after *ist?*

Comment: (b) ist richtig, aber ich weiss die Regel dafür nicht. Mein subjektiver Eindruck ist, dass man bei Relativsätzen im Deutschen immer oder viel häufiger das Komma setzen muss als im Englischen.

Comment: @nalply: Es ist wirklich fast *immer* – siehe meine Antwort. Es handelt sich hier allerdings nicht um einen Relativsatz, sondern um einen Interrogativsatz (glaube ich).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a comma, since “wie viele Stunden die Studenten an unserer Uni pro Woche arbeiten” is a subclause and subclauses are almost¹ always separated from the main clause with a comma (§ 74).

A helpful rule is that between two conjugated verbs (i.e., no infinitives) there always is at least one comma or one of a certain list of conjunctions, which predominantly includes *und* and *oder* – see § 72 for a full list. This list includes *wie,* but only in the rare case when it is used in the sense of *und* (I cannot even produce an example for this).

---

¹ The only exception being lists which contain normal objects as well as subclauses, e.g.:

> Thema des Schaubilds sind studentische Hilfskräfte und wie viele Stunden die Studenten an unserer Uni pro Woche arbeiten.